# How to extract specific words from a list as the list length changes?

Tags: python, string, parsing

Let's assume that I have a sample of the following strings:

- string = 'http/1.1 **abc-ad-sd-00**.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 **asc-ad-sd-11**.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [**gfef srFw:t reri pSs** ])'
- string1 = 'http/1.1 **abc-ad-sd-01**.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf f u did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 **asc-ad-sd-13**.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [**sff as  srFw:t reri pSs** ])'
- string2 = 'http/1.1 **abc-ad-sd-002**.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 **asc-ad-sd-14**.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [**rts as  f srFw:t reri pSs** ])'
- string3 = 'http/1.1 **abc-ad-sd-03**.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 **asc-ad-sd-15**.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [**tttts as t  srFw:t reri pSs** ])'

Here's what I did to get the bold strings:

```
If name == 'via':

name = “ID1”
string = header_line.split(' ')
b = (string[2].split('.'))
value = b[0]
headers[name] = value

#----------#

name_1 = “ID2”
string = header_line.split(' ')
b_1 = (string[9].split('.'))
value_1 = b_1[0]
headers[name_1] = value_1

#-----#

name_2 = “ID3”
string = header_line.split(' ')
b_2 = (string[11:])
value_2 = ''.join(b_2)
headers[name_2] = value_2

#----#
```

The problem with this is that it works only in certain situations. As you can see, there are 3 different strings so getting the bold strings by their index doesn't quite work. Ofcourse, this is not my complete code as these strings are stored in dict list.
Example: 
My initial output looks like this:

> [{‘item1’: '10574', 'Item2’: '69.241.51.134', ‘via’: ‘http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-00.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-11.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [tttts srFw:t reri pSs ]))’, ‘item4’: ’22’, 'HTTP RESPONSE': ['HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n']}, {…}, {…}]

And I want a different output like this based on the parsed values from the response above.

> [{‘item1’: '10574', 'Item2’: '69.241.51.134', ‘ID3’: 'tttts srFw:t reri pSs', ‘item4’: ’22’, ‘ID2’: ‘asc-ad-sd-11', 'HTTP RESPONSE': ['HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'], ‘ID1’: ‘abc-ad-sd-00’}, {…}, {…}]

So as you can see, I've bunch of dicts inside a list and for the key 'via', I want its value to be parsed into different substrings that I want and store them into new key values. I've already done this in my code.

Update: Thanks everyone for your responses. I've clarified my question. From your response, the value for ID1 and ID2 works however the value inside the [] isn't working because "tttts" won't be the same string in every response.

Another update: 
Thank you all for your help!! Using everyone's response, I tweaked my code a little and figured out how to get the values.

Comment: If your question was more elegant I could have tried to help more, but seems that you need to try using regular expressions:
http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/632/regular-expressions#t=201607251447256330505

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please see the updated question and let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expressions are your friend here. Something like `http\/1\.1 ([^\.]+)` works for this specific case.

```
import re
match = re.compile('http\/1\.1 ([^\.]+)').search(string)
value = match.group(1)
```

I would recommend splitting the strings with `string.split(',')` or whatever works to split each `http` entry.

You can learn more about python's regular expression module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), and you can test our your regular expressions in various websites, I like [this one.](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinionm you can use regex to get substring.

```
import re
pattern1 = r'\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+'
pattern2 = r'\[tttts .+\]'

#s is string you are checking
#pattern 1 will find substring like abc-ad-sd-00
re.findall(pattern1,s)
#pattern 2 will find substring like [tttts as t srFw:t reri pSs ]
re.findall(pattern2,s)
```

example:

```
s = 'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-00.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-11.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [tttts srFw:t reri pSs ])'

re.findall(r'\[tttts .+\]',s)
['[tttts srFw:t reri pSs ]']
re.findall(r'\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+',s)
['abc-ad-sd-00', 'asc-ad-sd-11']
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with a lot of text, then first thing to do is use/create an efficient memory-fiendly iterator over the strings. (let's assume you put it into function line_iterator)

The second thing to do is use a regular expression for getting the required parts of strings (assume you written and compiled the regexp). If there are always 2 similar pieces in each string, put them into groups in your regular expression.

Then you can do something like this:

```
import re

regexp = re.compile('<you regular expression>')

for line in line_iterator():
    match = regexp.match(line)
    if match:
        write_to_csv(match.groups())
```

Anyway, have a look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), they are worth it

Note:
1. compile your regular expression(s) if you need to use it a lot;
2. use generators for iterating over strings, don't keep the all in the memory;
3. better use 1 regular expression if you can

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [positive lookbehind regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
import re

p = """string = 'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-00.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-11.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [tttts srFw:t reri pSs ])'
string1 = 'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-01.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf f u did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-13.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [tttts as srFw:t reri pSs ])'
string2 = 'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-002.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-14.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [tttts as f srFw:t reri pSs ])'
string3 = 'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-03.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-15.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [tttts as t srFw:t reri pSs ])'
"""
s = re.findall("(?<=http/1.1\s)([\w\d\-]*)", p, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
s2 = re.findall("(?<=Server/1.2\s)\[([\w:\s]*)\]", p, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
print(list(s))
print(list(s2))

# will prints
# ['abc-ad-sd-00', 'asc-ad-sd-11', 'abc-ad-sd-01', 'asc-ad-sd-13', 'abc-ad-sd-002', 'asc-ad-sd-14', 'abc-ad-sd-03', 'asc-ad-sd-15']

# and
# ['dsddsf did:t yy p sS', 'tttts srFw:t reri pSs ', 'dsddsf f u did:t yy p sS', 'tttts as srFw:t reri pSs ', 'dsddsf did:t yy p sS', 'tttts as f srFw:t reri pSs ', 'dsddsf did:t yy p sS', 'tttts as t srFw:t reri pSs ']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can compile an expression before your loop and get each id you want from each string as you loop over them. The first regex will get the first two ids which have the same format. `\w+` looks for at least one word and `\d+` looks for at least one digit. The second expression wants the second occurrence of what's in the brackets so you start with `\[.*?` and then look for at least one word and a space before the rest of the expression.

```
import re

list_of_strings=[
    'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-00.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-11.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [gfef srFw:t reri pSs ])',
    'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-01.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf f u did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-13.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [sff as srFw:t reri pSs ])',
    'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-002.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-14.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [rts as f srFw:t reri pSs ])',
    'http/1.1 abc-ad-sd-03.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [dsddsf did:t yy p sS]), http/1.1 asc-ad-sd-15.sad.sdsd.der.net (Server/1.2 [tttts as t srFw:t reri pSs ])'
    ]

first_ids=r'\w+-\w+-\w+-\d+'
last_id=r'\[.*\[(\w+\s.*\w+:\w+\s\w+\s\w+)'
for url in list_of_strings:
    print(url)
    print(re.findall(first_ids,url)[0])
    print(re.findall(first_ids,url)[1])
    print(re.findall(last_id,url)[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please see the updated question and let me know if you need any clarification. Getting the first_ids worked however, for the last_id, it won't always be 'tttts' so trying to match that pattern won't work in my case :/

Comment: But if you look at other's response, maybe we can match "Server/1.2" in (Server/1.2 [tttts as t srFw:t reri pSs ] and get only the [tttts as t srFw:t reri pSs ]. Instead of matching "tttts".

Comment: @shishh03 updated the regex to work with the new strings

Comment: got it! :) I can't give you points because I'm new to stackover flow. And there were multiple similar responses that are all correct.